# Cannot receive a String with socket

Tags: java, c, sockets

I want to send an integer and a string from a Java server to a C client. I can read the integer but I have problem reading the String. this is my server code in java

```
ClientNumber++;
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
//dos.flush();
dos.writeInt(ClientNumber);

String randomString= getRandomValue(10,20);
dos.writeUTF(randomString);
```

This is the C client code:

```
int to_server_socket = -1;

void main ( void )
{

    char *server_name = SERVEURNAME;
    struct sockaddr_in serverSockAddr;
    struct hostent *serverHostEnt;
    long hostAddr;
    long status;
    char buffer[512];

    bzero(&serverSockAddr,sizeof(serverSockAddr));
    hostAddr = inet_addr(SERVEURNAME);
    if ( (long)hostAddr != (long)-1)
        bcopy(&hostAddr,&serverSockAddr.sin_addr,sizeof(hostAddr));
    else
    {
        serverHostEnt = gethostbyname(SERVEURNAME);
        if (serverHostEnt == NULL)
        {
            printf("gethost rate\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        bcopy(serverHostEnt->h_addr,&serverSockAddr.sin_addr,serverHostEnt->h_length);
    }
    serverSockAddr.sin_port = htons(8071);
    serverSockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    /* creation de la socket */
    if ( (to_server_socket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0)) < 0)
    {
        printf("creation socket client ratee\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    /* requete de connexion */
    if(connect( to_server_socket,
               (struct sockaddr *)&serverSockAddr,
               sizeof(serverSockAddr)) < 0 )
    {
        printf("demande de connection ratee\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    /* envoie de donne et reception */

    int value = htonl( 6 );
    int reply = 0;

    if( send( to_server_socket, &value, sizeof( value ), 0 ) != sizeof( value ) )
    {
        printf( "socket write failed");
        exit( -1 );
    }

    if( recv( to_server_socket, &reply, sizeof( reply ), MSG_WAITALL ) != sizeof( reply ) )
    {
        printf( "socket read failed");
        exit( -1 );
    }

    printf( "got reply: %d\n", ntohl( reply ) );

    char myString[30] = "";
    ssize_t nbytes=0;

    if ((nbytes = recv(to_server_socket, myString, sizeof(myString), 0 )) < 0)
    {
        perror("recv");
        exit(1);
    }
    myString[nbytes - 1] = '\0';


    printf("Recived String : %s",myString);


}
```

As a result I got my number and then a "socket read String failed" message.
if i don't do the test too i don't have any result

```
char myString[20] = "";
    recv( to_server_socket, &myString, sizeof( myString), 0 );
```

Comment: Could you monitor the network traffic using WireShark or other software and check if the string is delivered correctly?

Comment: with a java client it work perfectly

Comment: Your error checking doesn't _look_ valid for the string case. Why would the sent string be exactly 30 chars long?

Comment: don't have your instance reference labels start with capital letters, it is against convention

Comment: i used 30 as a maximal

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is with the below line:

```
 char myString[30] = "";

 if( recv( to_server_socket, &myString, sizeof( myString), 0 ) != sizeof( myString ))
```

Are you sure the string which you are sending from Java is of 30 characters. In above line you are checking the return value of recv to see if the value is 30, which may not be the case.

Just print the return value of recv and see if it gets any data and how many characters are present in that data.

Comment: No , it's a random String between 10 and 20 caracther, i puted 30 as a maximum

Comment: But, if it is a random string between 10 and 20 characters, then maximum you can get only 20 characters. So, recv function will receive only 20 characters and so, the condition will fail. So, I guess now, you must be clear with the problem.

Comment: I tried with 20 and it don't work so i wanted to trie with 30 because there are maybe some other caracther in C in the String like the \0 in the end of the String